# how do i control if an array is correct in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a group project and we're stuck on 1 subject. we are making a program were u can learn words for a test or something else. but everything works, the only problem we have is that we don't know how to make a 'check' button. Can someone help us?
we are using Microsoft Visual studio 2010, and we're using arrays for the words.
so how do we 'check' an array?

Comment: please provide more information on this.

Comment: can you provide a code or something?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: Oh my bad,  we want to make a program were u can learn words. For example;  a label shows the word and
The student fills in the good answer. But when the student fills in the answer he has to click on a button called “check”. If he has done that there has to show up a label where stands. “Your answer is incorrect/correct”. But we don’t know how to check if the answer is correct or incorrect.    I’m a student in the Netherlands so my apologies for my bad english.